# Kusto KQL Query - TimeGenerated issue

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have a script running on endpoints daily that sends a list of the applications installed to a Log Analytics workspace. I would like to query the current list of applications installed on each device.

The issue with the query below is that it includes applications that were reported on a previous occasion that have since either updated to newer version or have been uninstalled from the device. The first table below is illustrative of the starting table and the second table shows the result returned by the query. The row column is added for reference. In the second table, the apps on rows 3 and 8  have been updated to a new version and row 5 has been uninstalled. I would like the query to only return the latest set of software and versions by the last TimeGenerated for each device and not return these rows.

```
datatable(Row:int, DeviceName:string, AppName:string, AppVersion:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    1  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,2  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,3  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,4  ,"A" ,"Microsoft ToDo"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,5  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,6  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,7  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,8  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,9  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,10 ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,11 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,12 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,13 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,14 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,15 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,16 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
]
```

```
Table | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by DeviceName,AppName
```

| Row | DeviceName | AppName | AppVersion | TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Microsoft Teams | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z |
| 2 | A | Microsoft Word | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z |
| 3 | A | Microsoft Excel | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z |
| 4 | A | Microsoft Excel | 1.0.1 | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z |
| 5 | A | Microsoft ToDo | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z |
| 6 | B | Microsoft Teams | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z |
| 7 | B | Microsoft Word | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z |
| 8 | B | Microsoft Excel | 1.0.0 | 2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z |
| 9 | B | Microsoft Excel | 1.0.1 | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z |

Comment: Please add data sample + required results. If needed, add some explanation as to the transformation logic (e.g., how do you conclude that Teams was uninstalled?)

Comment: You might want to use this: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ (Github Markdown)

Comment: Thanks @DavidדודוMarkovitz. Tables added with Github Markdown. There was a typo in the post, it is row 5 (ToDo) in the resulting table that has been uninstalled. We conclude this because it was present in the dataset on 2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z, but not in the subsequent data sets.

Comment: What about the required results? You're original table allegedly contains the undesired query results (although that also doesn't make sense)

Comment: Did some edit. The *datatable* operator is a great way to collaborate data samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datatable(Row:int, DeviceName:string, AppName:string, AppVersion:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    1  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,2  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,3  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,4  ,"A" ,"Microsoft ToDo"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,5  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,6  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,7  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,8  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,9  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,10 ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,11 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,12 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,13 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,14 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,15 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,16 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
]
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by DeviceName, AppName
| partition hint.strategy=native by DeviceName 
  (
    order by TimeGenerated
    | where row_rank(TimeGenerated) == 1
  )
```

| DeviceName | AppName | TimeGenerated | Row | AppVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Microsoft Teams | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 8 | 1.0.0 |
| A | Microsoft Word | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 9 | 1.0.0 |
| A | Microsoft Excel | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 10 | 1.0.1 |
| B | Microsoft Teams | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 14 | 1.0.0 |
| B | Microsoft Word | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 15 | 1.0.0 |
| B | Microsoft Excel | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 16 | 1.0.1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: This query provides exactly the desired results - thank you very much!

Comment: @david Can you explain the reasoning behind why this is the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to acheive the same results, using *join*

```
datatable(Row:int, DeviceName:string, AppName:string, AppVersion:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    1  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,2  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,3  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,4  ,"A" ,"Microsoft ToDo"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-23T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,5  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,6  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,7  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-26T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,8  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,9  ,"A" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,10 ,"A" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z"
   ,11 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,12 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,13 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-25T16:31:57.688Z"
   ,14 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Teams" ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,15 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Word"  ,"1.0.0" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
   ,16 ,"B" ,"Microsoft Excel" ,"1.0.1" ,"2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z"
]
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by DeviceName, AppName
| as LatestAppsVersions
| join kind=inner 
  (
    LatestAppsVersions 
    | summarize TimeGenerated = max(TimeGenerated) by DeviceName
  ) on DeviceName, TimeGenerated
| project-away *1
```

| DeviceName | AppName | TimeGenerated | Row | AppVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Microsoft Excel | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 10 | 1.0.1 |
| A | Microsoft Word | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 9 | 1.0.0 |
| A | Microsoft Teams | 2022-09-27T06:02:39.66Z | 8 | 1.0.0 |
| B | Microsoft Excel | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 16 | 1.0.1 |
| B | Microsoft Word | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 15 | 1.0.0 |
| B | Microsoft Teams | 2022-09-28T10:45:37.168Z | 14 | 1.0.0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WUX0vDMBTF3wf7Dpc%20bdKVpF3TLrCHycQX9UGKgiKStXFkrs1oqtvED2/qZK5r9ycthPQm98c5t3ASVuh3Muede7mkIitsGPNPEfM7lnKqilxkUxtGi8X%209wPPlZDZthSJlF/zjOes4AlN9FroSrfdem63QD8YwLZGll5uRZxLJd8KiDhLVVnCDnJQuXGR6/bQoOd6ESIUudQbOIQ8Wb8M221gPMo8seB8htfAuFrFfG6go9/kRY6liQ7fbB6kiUHM5tHICMzm0cgIzbwETYyBmZdGBkYnvOAzGFhfuTzbix9hQj1M/cAhYbiFuHXIETMHIF4dcuTPHID0jeyEEUa071MvcDD5h/hGdg5AyAk7%20ATkpd36BvWRpiwXXxxYPn1N2apTCR4bLrowWe9k2Da8ym6m4EZfU4Wuqb8EU%20XBTIoM3kWWDEWmUVBK7myCq94Am4NdMRURMISasD1VJaELMqsIrTSUqha5nPG46LElW8MF/gFeUgnirAUAAA==)